# dropbox.js authentication error

Tags: javascript, dropbox

have a problem in the authentication process of dropbox.js. I used the same steps written in the documentation but I still can't authenticate my self. the error keep showing itself. I want to know if I am messing something in my process

```
var client = new Dropbox.Client({ key: '*************',
secret: '*************'});
client.authenticate({interactive: true}, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        alert('Authentication error: ' + error);
    }
});
alert(client.isAuthenticated()); //Here false is coming.
if (client.isAuthenticated()) {
    client.authenticate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What documentation are you following? That code is a bit weird in a few ways.

`{interactive: true}` is the default, so that parameter is unnecessary.

Then there's a conditional that says "If the user is already authenticated, then authenticate the user." (So that code should never execute.)

All that said, this code should sort of work. I would expect that the first time you run the app, you see "false" in an alert, but then after dismissing that alert, you should be redirected to authorize the app, and when you come back, you should see "true" and be authenticated.

Here's more typical code to do this:

```
var client = new Dropbox.Client({ key: '*************', secret: '*************'});
client.authenticate(function(error) {
    if (error) {
        alert('Authentication error: ' + error);
        return;
    }

    alert('Authenticated!');
    // Do authenticated things here.
});
```

Comment: i am sorry it seems that i have copied the wrong code but even with your code i get the same problem

Comment: What do you mean by "the same problem?" (What problem?)

Comment: i still get the authentication error message every time .do i need to implement something before this code snippet or do anything to make thing work ??

Comment: What authentication error message? Can you share the exact error you're receiving?